# How to read Unicode file as Unicode string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I have a file that is encoded in Unicode or UTF-8 (I don't know which). When I read the file in Python 3.4, the resulting string is interpreted as an ASCII string. How do I convert it to a Unicode string like `u"text"`?

Answer (score 8):

The term "Unicode" refers to the standard, not to a particular encoding.
Since files in computers are binary, there exist different ways of encoding Unicode data in binary files.  One of them is "UTF-8".

You can consult https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

An example taken from this document (in the section "Reading and Writing Unicode Data")

```
with open('unicode.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  for line in f:
    print(repr(line))
```

In python 3, unlike python2, unicode string constants are not written with a "u".